# How do I make a Firefox extension (add-on) that only becomes available for a specific site?

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to develop an extension that activates only for a specific domain.
I don't want it to appear in browser menus while not browsing this specific domain.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Possible: for the menus you could add a popupshowing listener that checks the currently loaded URL ([docs for the context menu, where this would make the most sense](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Modifying_the_context_menu)).

You can also update always visible elements (like status bar icons) whenever the currently displayed URL is changed. [This is done via gBrowser.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example.3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes).

Comment: and what about the toolbar button,short-key, status bar button? Can I do the same?

Comment: Well, when the button is clicked, you can check the current URL and not do anything if you don't need to. Hiding a toolbar button dynamically would be annoying.

Comment: I need exactly the hiding, the addon is beeing devloped for a specific domain only.

Comment: you noticed that I edited my answer to cover your second question, right?

Comment: regarding your update, after these events get triggeredm how do I hide/unhide the items from all the menus?

Comment: this is starting to look as a "give me teh codes" exercise. I'm sure you can find an answer to this question on your own.

Comment: whatever... you don't have to answer.